# Imgur embed does not show image in Angular web app

Tags: angular, imgur

Embedded Imgur image does not appear. Sometimes, it appears briefly, then disappears.

This page [does not contain the image.](http://citypinoy.com/forum/topic/3277bcc5-f010-4ff7-a775-f209118d22f7) It only shows a blank.

Looking at the source, it follows the same Imgur code. It also has embed.js at the bottom of the page.

```
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/lKOEEdd" data-context="false"><br>
    <a href="https://imgur.com/a/lKOEEdd">View on Imgur</a>
</blockquote>
```

It displays properly when I paste the same HTML on another site, like CodePen.

https://codepen.io/jonasarcangel/pen/OJVOZey

Comment: random behaviour needs more info, like screenshot of network tab in inspector panel, maybe they don't like origin of Your page?

Comment: can you post angular code that handles the page? I suspect it's not playing nicely with embed.js

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz instance of your issue?

Comment: Can you provide the component code

Comment: @num8er Is there a policy where they limit origins or that I have to apply to be accepted as an origin?

Comment: @JonasArcangel  can You provide screenshot of network tab to understand why imgur not showing. I’m sure there must be some non positive status code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

Because of server side rendering, your `blockquote` embed element is processed too early by imgur's scripts. The iframe with its content is then replaced by a blockquote element again when your component is rendered.

You need to call `window.imgurEmbed.createIframe()` once your component is rendered client side

**What happens is**

- the server side rendered page is returned by your server, with all html elements, including the blockquote element and a script link to `embed.js`
- html data is parsed by the browser
- `embed.js run`, and adds a new imgur's script, `embed-controler.js`
- that `embed-controller.js` adds an iframe for all elements matching the selector `blockquote.imgur-embed-pub`
- the iframe is displayed and you see the image and replaces the `blockquote`
- the client angular app is bootstrapped and performs all the rendering again (Note that this is normal angular universal behaviour)
- Your `app-shell-embed` component is rendered, and replaces its content with the `blockquote` element.

**Solution**

Call `window.imgurEmbed.createIframe()` in your code once the components with imgur embeds have been rendered to force imgur to do the replacement again;

```
if(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId))//Call the update client side only
{
    window.imgurEmbed.createIframe();
}
```

You can verify this by executing `window.imgurEmbed.createIframe()` in chrome's dev tools console for the [url you posted](https://citypinoy.com/forum/topic/3277bcc5-f010-4ff7-a775-f209118d22f7).

Comment: Yes it worked! This explains why it appears for a bit and then disappears (upon completed render). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, why it's not working at your end, can you please share your code instance. It would be easier for the StackOverflow team to debug.

I have implemented the Imgur image shared by you in one of my angular app and its working. [Please see the stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bmn7hw).

I have added the blockquote code inside app.component.html

```
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/lKOEEdd">
  <a href="//imgur.com/a/lKOEEdd">Papa BearBakehouse</a>
</blockquote>
```

And I have moved the script tag inside the index.html

```
<script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Can you please confirm if your implementation is the same, if not can you please share your code.

Comment: Yes any other site, it works. My link codepen link also shows that it works.

Comment: Is there any way you can replicate the issue, so that we can see your code and debug.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue some time ago and what I did was changing the href by the actual one.

From this one:

```
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/lKOEEdd" data-context="false">
    <a href="https://imgur.com/a/lKOEEdd">View on Imgur</a>
</blockquote>
```

To this one:

```
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/lKOEEdd" data-context="false">
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/a/lKOEEdd.jpg">View on Imgur</a>
</blockquote>
```

In order to obtain the actual URL: right-click on the image and open in new tab.